# Wpf: Update content using scroll position

Tags: c#, wpf

You have a stackpanel with many buttons arranged vertically.  The buttons contain either a date or a time.  They are intermingled:  "Monday", "1pm", "7pm", "Tuesday", "3pm", "11pm", "Wednesday". You can scroll down the list of buttons with a scrollviewer.

**Tricky part**:  The top button must always show a day (i.e "Tuesday") not a time. This is to know which day the times belong to as you scroll down. For example: If you scrolled down one button the example would read: "1pm", "7pm", "Tuesday", "3pm", "11pm", "Wednesday".  And you wouldn't know what day 1pm belonged to anymore without scrolling up.

Here is what I have so far:

**XAML:**

```
<DockPanel>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="Monday" Background="Red"/>
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer Name="sv1" CanContentScroll="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <StackPanel Name="sp1">
                <Button Content="1pm"/>
                <Button Content="7pm"/>
                <Button Content="Tuesday" Background="Red"/>
                <Button Content="3pm"/>
                <Button Content="11pm"/>
                <Button Content="Wednesday" Background="Red"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

**C#**

```
public partial class myWindow : Window
{        
    public myWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //"Logical scrolling"
    private void spLineUp(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((IScrollInfo)sp1).LineUp();
    }
    private void spLineDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((IScrollInfo)sp1).LineDown();
    }
}
```

How would you change the content using the scroll position?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a property called "VerticalOffset"  that keeps track of the row in logical scrolling.  Knowing the row number then allowed updating the content.

C#

```
    private void sChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TopButton.Content = e.VerticalOffset.ToString();
    }
```

XAML

```
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="Date" Background="Red" Name="TopButton"/>
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer Name="sv1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" CanContentScroll="True" ScrollChanged="sChanged">
            <StackPanel Name="sp1">
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```